# MYSQL update into select 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I use this query (insert into select 3 tables) to insert my rows in the mysql table.

```
"INSERT INTO test (catid_1, descat_1, catid_2, descat_2, id_user, user)
 SELECT '$_POST[cat_1]',t1.desc AS descat_1, '$_POST[cat_2]', t2.desc AS descat_2, 
 $_POST[id_user]',t3.user FROM t1, t2, t3 
 WHERE t1.idcat_1='$_POST[cat_1]' and t2.idcat_2='$_POST[cat_2]' 
 and t3.id_user='$_POST[id_user]'";
```

Now I'd like to use the same logic to UPDATE my rows (update into select 3 table) in the mysql table.

tables structure

```
t1
`idcat_1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idcat_1`)

t2
`idcat_2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idcat_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idcat_2`)

t3
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
```

Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE test AS t
INNER JOIN t1 ON -- join conditon
INNER JOIN t2 ON ...
INNER JOIN t3 ON ... 
SET t.catid_1 = '$_POST[cat_1]',
    t.descat_1 = t1.desc,
    ....
 WHERE t1.idcat_1='$_POST[cat_1]' 
   and t2.idcat_2='$_POST[cat_2]' 
   and t3.id_user='$_POST[id_user]'
```

It is not clear how the four  tables are joined, you will need to supply the join condition for each `JOIN`.

---

### Update 1

From the tables' structures that you just posted in your updated question, it seems like neither of the three tables `test`, `t1` nor `t2` related to the table `t3` by any keys. In this key you didn't need to join with this table `t3` and only join the tables `test`, `t1` and `t2`. Assuming that:

- `test` relates to `t1` with `test.catid_1 = t1.idcat_1`.
- `t1` relates to `t2` with `t1.idcat_1 = t2.idcat_1`.

Like this:

```
UPDATE test AS t
INNER JOIN t1 ON t.catid_1 = t1.idcat_1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.idcat_1 = t2.idcat_1
SET t.catid_1 = '$_POST[cat_1]',
    t.descat_1 = t1.desc,
    ....
 WHERE t1.idcat_1='$_POST[cat_1]' 
   and t2.idcat_2='$_POST[cat_2]'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not seem to complete correctly the join clause. I set this INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.catid_1 = t2.catid_1. Can you give me some help? thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi - Ofcourse , can you please post the three tables' structures? it will be helpful.